# Laravel Nexmo Config from Database

Tags: laravel, vonage

Is there any way to move Nexmo configuration on `.env` to database on Laravel? I found nothing about this on Laravel's documentation.

Comment: What is Nexmo? What have you tried already? What failed? Moving configuration from plaintext to a database sounds fairly straightforward, but we can't help you if you don't have a MVCE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Nexmo is SMS service provider. Moving configuration from .env or config folder on laravel to database is absolute pain. Because it is not designed to be that. I just ask if someone has made more simple method on this case.

Comment: Create a model, migration and a seed and that's it? You don't actually need the model but it makes it easer to access the config. You can set config just like any other thing you would set in a database.

Comment: config file describe as array, we can't even make variable on that.

Comment: Take a look at the config helper, sure you can: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-config

Comment: does config helper just supposed to be read the configuration ? not change it. Tried it and not work ..

Comment: It can do both? All described in the docs